# How to correctly rebuild a C++ project as a Debug using CMake for further profiling with Valgrind?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, cmake, valgrind

I have a C++ project that I previously built using CMake. Now I need to rebuild it as Debug so that I can profile it with Valgrind to find code bottlenecks. However, I have a problem with the rebuild.

I go to the root directory with the project:
`cd MyProj`
Later I start the process of building and installing the project:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/user/Desktop ..
make -j4 install
```

After that I rebuild the project as a Вebug in the following way:

```
cd ..
mkdir Debug
cd Debug
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
make
```

After rebuilding, I run the project for profiling with Valgrind:
`valgrind --tool=callgrind ./MyProg` 
But in the resulting file there are no functions of my project, i.e. Valgrind does not see them (see screenshot). I suspect that this is because I rebuilt the project incorrectly as a Debug. Please help me with rebuilding the project as a Debug for further profiling, as I have just started doing this and need some help.
[Valgrind does not see my project functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEIG2.png)

Comment: What are the exact compilation flags being used?  `make VERBOSE=1` will give you the full commands being executed.

Comment: profiling Debug mode build? This is not a good idea. Maybe you need just `RelWithDebInfo` configuration `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`?

Comment: Ditto what Merek said.  Profiling a non-optimized build is not a useful exercise.  A coworker did that on our project, and he made the debug build x10 faster in that critical area, but his changes made the release build x3 slower in that same critical area.

Comment: @Eljay Ok, I will try this way. Am I making any mistakes when rebuilding?

Comment: @StephenNewell So, I try this command, but I get very long output)

Comment: You only need to look at one of the lines from the compiler and look at the options.